# why this sentence has this grammatical structure? 話し手も相手も共通に知っている場合

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に, particle-は, particle-を

The phrase "話し手も相手も共通に知っている場合" was translated in this board as "When both the speaker and listener know the subject"

I dont understand 2 things about this sentence. What's the use of ni in this phrase. It doesnt seem to match with any of the uses of "ni" I know. Isnt 話し手も相手も共通 the topic of the sentence and should be marked with "は". And why "the subject" isnt before the 知っている verb and it isnt marked with を ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand "共通に" can be correspoond to "both."

"話し手も相手も共通に話題を知っている場合" = "When（場合） both（共通に） the speaker（話し手） and（も） listener（相手） know（知っている） the subject（話題(を)）"

"話し手も相手も共通に知っている場合" = "When both the speaker and listener know the subject"

"話し手も相手も知っている場合" = "When the speaker and listener know the subject"

The nuance of difference is quite week.

Answer (score 2):

共通に is an adverb modifying 知っている.
It is added for emphasis.
話し手も相手も知っている場合 is also a valid expression differing only by nuance.

Comment: if they have different nuances, could you make a literal translation of both phrases for the nuances to be more clear or the literal translation of both nuances is the same? I appreciate the info in your answer and the time you took to answer but I dont quite get it

Comment: Sunny's "both" is perfect.